# My URL for payment notification result 404

Tags: magento2, module, payment-gateway, notification

I have problem with notifications URL in my custom payment gateway.
I have Urlnotification class under Block folder where I put

```
namespace MyPayment\MyGateway\Block;

use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;

/**
 * Class Urlnotification
 *
 * @package MyPayment\MyGateway\Block
*/

 class Urlnotification extends Field {

     /**
      * @param AbstractElement $element
      *
      * @return string
     */
     protected function _getElementHtml(AbstractElement $element) {

          return $this->getBaseUrl() . 'mypayment/mygateway/response';
     }
 }
```

Under 'Controller' folder I have subfolder 'Response' with 'Index.php' class where I have all logic to handle reciving POST request with data to manipulating transaction / payment.

When I testing it local via Postman everything works fine - I make POST request on URL (http://my.localhost/index.php/mypayment/mygateway/response) with necessary form-data but when I try to test it on remote server I have always 404, no matter what URL I requested for example: http://mysite/index.php/mypayment/mygateway/response or http://mysite/mypayment/mygateway/response

What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT** I found out I can recive POST request, only problem is 'session_id' in POST form-data, without it all works fine, but I have to handle param like 'session_id', this is what external API sent, I can't change it

Comment: Did you clean cache after activate the module? Seems like route is not working at all.

Comment: @PradiptaSarkar Yup, I cleaned cache via admin panel, via console, flush them but there is no difference

Comment: @PradiptaSarkar additional info - 404 is only when I make POST with form-data, when I make POST without any data it redirect me on the main site, with GET is this same, redirect to main page

Comment: Ok, I have noticed another thing - now I can recive POST request but when I pass 'session_id' parameter in form-data it result 404, and it's only with this one parameter which has underscore, I can't modify it to 'sessionId' or similar because it come from external API, how can I go around it?

Comment: First of all, the API response should come as Json not form data. session_id might be a preserve variable and attached with a specific task. So when you sending data to the url as form data it's not working as expected. You may try with json response.

Comment: Thanks for the answear! I know it should be Json's but I can't rebuild this external API, I need to walk around this